# Extracting each list of a lists

Tags: python, list

I have the following list of lists:

```
list_sample = [[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6], [0.021, 0.021, 0.021, 0.021, 0.021, 0.021, 0.021], [0.022, 0.022, 0.022, 0.022, 0.022, 0.022, 0.022],...]
```

I'd like to extract each list and attribute it to another list such as:

```
for i,line in enumerate(list_sample):
    if  i==0:
        Z_level=line
    if i==1:
        XD1=line
    if i==2:
        XD2=line
    .....
```

Is there a way to make this more efficiently? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or (complementing RobEarl) answer,

```
Z_level, XD1, XD2, ... = list_sample
```

However, if you don't know how big is your list_sample you need to look for how to dynamically set variables in python. You can check some of that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-in-python-via-to-a-while-loop)

Answer (score 3):

If I read you correctly, you want to assign the first sub-list to Z_level, the second to XD1...

```
Z_level, XD1, XD2 ... = list_sample
```

If you only want to assign 3 things:

```
Z_level, XD1, XD2 = list_sample[:3]
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for a loop:

```
Z_level = list_sample[0]
XD1 = list_sample[1]
XD2 = list_sample[2]
...
```

Answer (score 2):

To infinity, try this ...

```
for i,line in enumerate(list_sample):
    if i == 0:
        vars()["Z_level"] = line
        continue
    vars()["XD"+str(i)] = line
```

This is just for fun, but you should probably **not** use this, read the comments by @defuz and @DSM as to why.

This is probably a better solution :

```
lists = {}
for i,line in enumerate(list_sample):
    if i == 0:
        lists["Z_level"] = line
        continue
    lists["XD"+str(i)] = line
```

Comment: I think this is not the case when to use such magic. Create local variables for a large number of similar values ​​is evil. In the end we did not even know how many local variables we have created.

Comment: @defuz I'm new to python. I'm just playing around. :)

Comment: This won't even work if it's in a function, because modifications to `locals()` aren't guaranteed to be respected.  Simply use a standard dictionary instead.

Comment: @DSM I didn't know that, I'll post a warning.